# how to make an object turn around a point in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, coordinates

The problem is demonstrated in the image below 
[image: the problem of defining angles]

In other words, how to exactly compute the x and y coordinates for every frame?

```
ctx.arc(x,y,radius,0,pi*2,false)
```

because after incrementing one coordinate, I have a problem how to compute the other

I tried this but doesn't work

```
var step=2,x=100,y=100,r=50,coordinates=[[x,y-r]];
for(var i=1;i <r;i+=step){
bx=x;
x+=step;
y=y-Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2)-Math.pow(bx-x,2))
coordinates[i]=[x,y];
}
```

a jsfiddle will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("#c");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var speed = 10; // Lower is faster


function animate(t){
    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect (0 , 0 ,canvas.width ,canvas.height );
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
    
    // First circle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    // rotate + move along
    ctx.rotate((t/speed)/100);
    ctx.translate(100,0);
    
    // Orbiting cirle
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
    
    ctx.restore();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="512" height="512"></canvas>
```

Comment: wooow that's so cool 
i was thinking that i have to use complex for loops and math functions like sin / cosin/ atan2.......

Comment: where does it come the t in the animate function for we didn't call it with that parameter any where

Comment: The `requestAnimationFrame` callback has one single argument, a `DOMHighResTimeStamp`, which indicates the current time for when `requestAnimationFrame` starts to fire callbacks.